# Error: Failed to parse XML for the provided file

Tags: python, xml

I'm running a program provided by an opensource platform. When I load the data I get the error:
**Failed to parse XML for the provided file. Error: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 6.**
Then I find the code that reports the error:

```
    # xml parse errors
    except ET.ParseError as e:
        log.error(f"Failed to parse XML for the provided file. Error: {e}")
        return False
```

The code containing line 1 in the file ET, ElementTree:

```
  __all__ = [
# public symbols
"Comment",
"dump",
"Element", "ElementTree",
"fromstring", "fromstringlist",
"iselement", "iterparse",
"parse", "ParseError",
"PI", "ProcessingInstruction",
"QName",
"SubElement",
"tostring", "tostringlist",
"TreeBuilder",
"VERSION",
"XML", "XMLID",
"XMLParser", "XMLPullParser",
"register_namespace",
"canonicalize", "C14NWriterTarget",
]
```

But I still don't know how to figure this out. Hope someone knows the solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you thought about sharing your own code where you use this opensource stuff?

Comment: What program do you use? What data do you load? What is the __all__ thing? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If the XML is the problem, please [edit] your question and include the XML (or at least the beginning, if the error is at line 1 already). Note also that stackoverflow is about programming questions; if you just try to use a program you downloaded somewhere, your question may be off-topic here.